# inserting variable into html page with innerhtml on page load

Tags: javascript, html

I have inherited an html page which displays stats for the sales team. I have inserted a cut down version of it here

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <br>

  <div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;"></div><br>

  <div>
    <table border="2" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" style=
    "background-color: white; border-collapse: collapse; text-align: center; width: 900px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr style=
        "background-color: #f7941e; color: white; padding-bottom: 4px; padding-top: 5px;">
        <th>
            <div style="text-align: center;">
              <span style=
              "font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: small;">Total
              Accounts</span>
            </div>
          </th>

        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <div style="text-align: justify;">
              <div style="text-align: center;">
                <span style=
                "color: #20124d; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 75px; font-weight: bold;">
                200</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you look you can see the sales figure is currently 200. now let;s say then have to change it to "300".

The system they use does not display a preview of the table they can edit, so they edit the html directly by hunting through the code. What I'd like to do is list the variables at the top of the page in javascript and have the guys edit them there, rather than hunting through the code.

So something like

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

myVar = "300";
document.getElementById('total_accounts').innerHTML = myVar;
</script>


<title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <br>

  <div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;"></div><br>

  <div>
    <table border="2" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" style=
    "background-color: white; border-collapse: collapse; text-align: center; width: 900px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr style=
        "background-color: #f7941e; color: white; padding-bottom: 4px; padding-top: 5px;">
        <th>
            <div style="text-align: center;">
              <span style=
              "font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: small;">Total
              Accounts</span>
            </div>
          </th>

        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <div style="text-align: justify;">
              <div style="text-align: center;">
                <span id="total_accounts" style=
                "color: #20124d; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 75px; font-weight: bold;"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This way I can list all of the variables at the top of the page. Unfortunately, it doesn't work, it displays no value in the cell. Where have I gone wrong?

thanks

Comment: Shift your script block to the end of page (before body end).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you won't use jQuery, then your script should be:

```
window.onload = function(){
myVar = "300";
document.getElementById('total_accounts').innerHTML = myVar;
        };
```

Here you can look how it works: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/uga5qotj/)

Answer (score 0):

window.load is one option or you can even call a function from body tag as shown below

```
<script>  
function changeAccount(){
  var myVar = "300";
  document.getElementById('total_accounts').innerHTML = myVar;
}
</script>

<title>test</title>
</head>

<body onload="changeAccount()">
```